# How to do a DFS on a list of objects which also contains a list of objects

Tags: java, list, algorithm, search, depth-first-search

How can I recursively search an object which has a List of same objects and breaks when I find a specific object in it.

Example this is my object, and each object can go deeper with a list of its own

```
MyObject:

List<MyObject>
    MyObject <- 2) Tag this and move onto next object
        List<MyObject>
            MyObject
                List<MyObject>
            MyObject <- 1) BOOM found what I want
                List<MyObject>
    MyObject
    MyObject
    MyObject
    MyObject
    MyObject
    MyObject
    MyObject
    MyObject
```

I essentially want to do a DFS on my list. I've tried to recursively do it but I can't seem to exit it properly.

[image]

Comment: DFS is a graph algorithm.  To apply it to your data, you have to come up with a way to view them as a graph.  I'm sure that's within your abilities.

Comment: You would get much better responses when you include some code for the DFS.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem explained above , this solution might help you

```
private static boolean search(Object object, Object searchingObject) {
    List<?> al = (ArrayList) object;
    for (int index = 0; index < al.size(); index++) {
        if (al.get(index) instanceof List) {
             if(search(al.get(index), searchingObject)) {
                 return true;
             }
        } else {
            Iterator<Object> itr = (Iterator<Object>) al.iterator();
            Object o;
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                o = itr.next();
                if (o.equals(searchingObject)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

main method for the abve code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList> o = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> o1 = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add(2);
    al.add(3);
    al.add(4);
    o1.add(al);
    o.add(o1);
    Integer i = 4;//Object which has to be searched
    System.out.println(search(o,i));//returning true
}
```